# how to setup mvc net model with ILists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am passing back a List of objects to a webapi controller. i need to add 2 more properties, they are both Lists. I am stuck on how to setup my classes.

model/apicontroller

```
  public class DataPoints
{
    public string sqft { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }

}
public class Products
{
    public string product { get; set; }

}
public class Data
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<DataPoints> DataPoints { get; set; }
    public IList<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
public class ExportLegendController : ApiController
{

    // POST: api/ExportLegend
    [HttpPost]
    public PDF Post([FromBody]List<Data> data)
    {
```

here is what I am passing back
[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as long as your JSON object has properties called dataPoints and products - whereas at the moment they're called data and product (or vice versa of course, you could rename your .NET model.)

I also find IEnumerables are more reliably deserialised.